# Google dataproc spark cluster with too many Preemptible nodes sometime hangs

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, google-cloud-dataproc

When running spark cluster on dataproc with only 2 nonpreemptable worker nodes and other 100~ preemptable nodes I sometimes get a cluster that is not usable at all due to too many connection errors, datanode errors, lost executors but still being tracked for the heartbeat...
Always getting errors like that:

```
18/08/08 15:40:11 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DataStreamer: Error Recovery for BP-877400388-10.128.0.31-1533740979408:blk_1073742308_1487 in pipeline [DatanodeInfoWithStorage[10.128.0.35:9866,DS-60d8a566-a1b3-4fce-b9e2-1eeeb4ac840b,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[10.128.0.7:9866,DS-9f1d8b17-0fee-41c7-9d31-8ad89f0df69f,DISK]]: datanode 0(DatanodeInfoWithStorage[10.128.0.35:9866,DS-60d8a566-a1b3-4fce-b9e2-1eeeb4ac840b,DISK]) is bad.
```

And errors reporting `Slow ReadProcessor read fields for block BP-877400388-10.128.0.31-1533740979408:blk_1073742314_1494`

from what I see there appear to be something not functioning correctly for those clusters but nothing is reported to indicate that.

Plus the application master is also created on a preemptable node why is that?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/compute/preemptible-vms#how_preemptibles_work_with_cloud_dataproc), the number of preemptible workers needs to be less than 50% of the total number of nodes within your cluster to have the best results. Regarding the application master within the preemptible node, you could [report](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#bug_reports) this behavior by filling an issue tracker for [Dataproc](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187133&template=1100109).

Comment: +1 to what F10 says. If you're using that many preemptibles, you have to be comfortable with preemption and loosing your progress. Preemptibles work well for short jobs (that run in minutes to an hour) perhaps from a WorkflowTemplate, but not so well for longer lived clusters where you should have even < 50% pVM ratio.